# Why do I receive HTTP is not supported in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient

I am trying to make a http request from Xamarin.Forms, but struggling with it.

When I try to do an http request I get an error that says "**HTTP is not supported**".

`var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var json = httpClient.GetStringAsync(urlToAccess).Result; 
//after the above line is called, variable json = "reason=HTTP+is+not+supported.&status=fail&errorcode=180"`

I tried to use "**HttpWebRequest**" class, but I receive the same errorcode (*180, HTTP is not supported*).

Hope you can help me with some ideas on this matter.

Comment: Probably need to use https in your URL

Comment: lol, it works, gosh how did I missed this, thank you Joe

Comment: the SERVER is telling you it doesn't support HTTP